# How could I ignore JavaScript lint warning in Visual Studio 2017 Community?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, visual-studio-2017, lint

Recently I installed Visual Studio 2017 Community.
And I open the solution created by VS 2013.
In my project there is include Angular 1.5.7, then VS 2017 give a warning like this.(TS7027)
[image]

I check the Tool->Option, but I have no idea how to ignore these.